# sh: Directory check fails when directory exist

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have the following code to test for directory existence:

```
PROJECT="somedir"
if [ -d ~/migrations/$PROJECT ] ; then
    echo "Test"
fi

dst_dir="~/migrations/$PROJECT"
if [ -d "$dst_dir" ] ; then
    echo "Test 2"
fi
```

For some reason it only outputs *Test*. I would expect it to output both *Test* and *Test 2*.

Rather new to shell scripting, what am I missing? I feel like it has something to do with `~`.

Comment: For your future convenience, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) would have pointed out that `~` doesn't expand in quotes.

Comment: Obviously makes no difference here, but you should probably still quote "$PROJECT" by convention in single brackets.

Answer (score 4):

Because tilde `~` needs to be outside quotes.

Try:

```
dst_dir=~/migrations/$PROJECT
```

`~` doesn't expand when quoted.

**TESTING:**

```
s="~"
ls "$s"
ls: ~: No such file or directory

s=~
ls "$s"
# list comes here
```

Comment: Because ~ is a shell expansion. If you wrap it in a string, it gets quoted and not expanded anymore. Try using `$HOME` instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2034467/805196 for more detail.

Comment: @Andrea Schiavini, that explains it. Thanks.